# How do I use MATLAB in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, matlab

For my computer science classes, we are using MATLAB to code all of our homework / quiz problems, etc. 
I use eclipse already for my Java coding, and my Android coding. Is it possible to use Eclipse to code in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB plugin for eclipse:

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/matclipse/

However, you will still need MATLAB to run your code. Possibly do that over the slow remote connection?

Comment: So I can code on my laptop with Eclipse, and I could save the .m program; and just can't test it until I run that program in the actually MATLAB program, one way or another?

Comment: If you set your matlab binaries and path to your project preferences you can run your scripts in eclipse, the results are presented in a console on matlab perspective.

Comment: That's true, but from what the OP said (and edited out by @Lorem Ipsum), he doesn't seem to have a local copy of MATLAB, otherwise he would be using that.