# Do code/text editors not require the actual program itself?

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, editor, text-editor

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034764/how-do-i-use-matlab-in-eclipse) while looking for an editor that could handle both C++ and Matlab. (I've only recently learned about such editors.)

Does this mean that I can run C++ code on OSX using an editor such as Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A text editor is just that. An editor for text. Typically, for programming, we use a text-editor that "understands" the language to some extent, but it's not a compiler. You ALSO need a compilter to be able to RUN your code.

The "understanding" the language is so that it can for example highlight the syntax (pale red for comments, blue for keywords, green for variable declarations, or whatever the settings for those things are). Sometimes it will also understand things like "If you type the beginning of a name and press , expands to the full name" and "If you have typed the name of a class followed by `.` or `->`, show a list of the possible options for what members we could be using", or "If we type the name of a function, show the parameters that go into it").

To run a C++ program, you need to compile it with a compiler. There are free ones, and expensive ones, and ones that don't cost a huge amount of money. I'm no expert on Mac OS X, so I don't really know what the commercial options are, but I believe both `gcc` and `clang` are available, which are free, and good quality compilers.

Eclipse is an IDE (integrated development environment), which is the "next step on" from a "programmers text editor" - it has an editor, but also the ability to connect to a compiler and a debugger, so you can write your code, save it and hit  and it will compile the code for you, hit  and it starts the debugger so you can set breakpoints, step through the code etc, etc. But you still need the set of compilers and debuggers installed on the machine.

Eclipse has "plugins" for a large number of languages, such as C++, Java and Python.

Answer (score 1):

You don't run programs in a text editor, you just use it to edit the code. An IDE may have commands to compile, run, and debug the program, but if you don't have a local implementation of the language you won't be able to use these features. The rest of the IDE's functionality can be done without the language implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A good editor / IDE is modular in its design.  http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/